# Add js file and call a js function from C#

Tags: javascript, c#, internet-explorer, browser-extension

I am developing an IE Addon using C#. I have javascript functions in a js file. I need to attach the js file to C# and call js functions from C#, send value to js and it must return a value.

**JS File - sample.js :**

```
function sample (str) {
   //js code
}
```

**C# File :**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
   //Need to call sample(str) and pass 'str' value to the js function.
}
```

P.S : I tried  the below code but getting object reference not set to instance of an object

```
Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;   
page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("sample","sample.js");
page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page),"Test","<script type='text/javascript'>sample('str');</script>");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Thanks. But can you suggest a working code for the above case? What is wrong in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your ASP.Net application must be calling your C# callback:

```
<asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" Text="Do something" onclick="button1_Click" />
```

One way to solve this problem is to simply add an `OnClientClick` attribute:

```
<asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" Text="Do something" onclick="button1_Click" OnClientClick="sample('someValue');" />
```

It all depends where this "`str`" parameter value comes from, which you want to pass to the JavaScript function...

Comment: I am using only c# and not asp.net. Am creating a browser extension using addin express. Could you provide a code in c# when i could send a value to js and it will return another value